# Programmatically translate taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a vocabulary of taxonomy terms I get through `taxonomy_term_load($tid);` and displays in views page. How do I get and display the terms depending on the user's language?

Answer (score 0):

Basing on [Using the i18n API from other modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/1114010), the code should be the following one.

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid); 
$translated = i18n_string_translate("taxonomy:term:$tid:name", $term->name);
```

Comment: It does not work displays all terms in both English and in Russian.